# Какие именно процессы проверяются в if (pid > 0)?

Tags: linux, c

Создать N процессов, если один завершился - создать новый. Есть код:

```
pid_t pid; 
pid_t pid1;
pid1 = getpid();

for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    if(pid1 == pid)
    {
        pid = fork();
    }   
}

while(1)
{
    if (pid > 0)
    {
        wait(0);
        pid = fork();
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие процессы(аля от 0..N и т.п.) проверяются в строке if (pid > 0)

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

Comment: Дополните вопрос,  как вы поняли значения, которые возвращает fork. Ссылку на мануал см. коммент выше.

Comment: **Никакой не проверяется**. Переменная `pid` в вашем коде не получает никакого осмысленного значения. Это неинициализированная переменная.